# Internal error in Cloud Firestore (21.5.0)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-espresso

I'm getting this error while writing test cases using expresso. I have been getting a Firebase Firestore crash. The crash explains what is happening pretty well, but I have no clue how to actually fix it. I am assuming it is an issue with a Gradle file It will give me this error, can you please help me in this?

I'm using this gradle **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'*

```
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:534)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(AsyncQueue.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:148)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$200(ShadowMessageQueue.java:38)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:126)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:386)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:278)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:260)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceBy(Scheduler.java:243)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceBy(Scheduler.java:233)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.setIdleState(Scheduler.java:88)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:123)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:347)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:398)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:102)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:107)
    at org.robolectric.android.fakes.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySyncInternal(RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.java:61)
    at org.robolectric.android.fakes.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.java:43)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:358)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:529)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:256)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;)V
    at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.<clinit>(ListenRequest.java:849)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.FirestoreGrpc.getListenMethod(FirestoreGrpc.java:396)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.<init>(WatchStream.java:61)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.createWatchStream(Datastore.java:115)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.<init>(RemoteStore.java:167)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider.createRemoteStore(MemoryComponentProvider.java:72)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ComponentProvider.initialize(ComponentProvider.java:135)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(FirestoreClient.java:249)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0(FirestoreClient.java:96)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$1.run(FirestoreClient.java)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:436)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call(AsyncQueue.java)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:322)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(AsyncQueue.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229)
    ... 1 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
testOptions {
    unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.url', 'https://local-mirror/repo'
        systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.repo.id', 'local'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 44
    versionName "3.0.8"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion
implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.5'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
testImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0-rc01")
testImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-rc01")
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.3.1'
testImplementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
 }
```

Comment: Can you add your module-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Sure. Please check updated question with build.gradle code.

Comment: A few things. Don't use Support library artifacts if you're already using AndroidX. Migrate them completely to AndroidX. There probably seems to be a conflict in a transitive dependency of one of your libraries, which might be using a protobuf dependency. You can try running `gradlew app:dependencies` to find this conflict. Try updating the dependencies to their latest versions.