# Internal error in Cloud Firestore (22.1.0) when running instrumentation test

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-instrumentation, protobuf-java

I get an internal error message from Cloud Firestore. When I run this test, the App is getting a list of items from Firebase. This takes a while. In the meantime, the test stops.

Every library is updated to the latest version. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670837/internal-error-in-cloud-firestore-21-5-0) does not give a satisfying answer. The error only occurs when running the test, the actual App is fine.

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeTest {

    @get:Rule
    var reportHelper: ReportHelper? = Factory.getReportHelper()

    @get:Rule
    var activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    // Executes tasks in a synchronous [TaskScheduler]
    @get:Rule
    var syncTaskExecutorRule = SyncTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun goToHomeScreen() {
        onView(withId(R.id.navigation_home)).perform(ViewActions.click())
    }

    @Test
    fun scrollToNextVideo() {
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler)).perform(swipeUp())
    }

    @After
    fun TearDown() {
        reportHelper?.label("Stopping App")
    }
}
```

build.gradle (App level):

```
android {
    configurations.all() { configuration ->
//    exclude group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-javalite"

       exclude group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-java"
//    exclude group: "io.grpc", module: "grpc-protobuf-lite" // tried this, but App fails to compile
}
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.0"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.2"
}
```

Here are my [dependencies.txt](http://jimclermonts.nl/downloads/dependencies.txt)

Stacktrace:

```
Testing started at 18:40 ...

02/23 18:40:39: Launching 'HomeTest' on Samsung SM-A515F.
App restarts successfully without requiring a re-install.
Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -m  --no-window-animation  -e debug false -e class 'eu.theappfactory.someapp.data.ui.home.HomeTest' eu.theappfactory.someapp.acc.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Connected to process 981 on device 'samsung-sm_a515f-R58N52ZCJZL'.

Started running tests

java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (22.1.0).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:534)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;)V in class Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite' appears in /data/app/eu.theappfactory.someapp.acc.test-K43eWkkKbA6iBOHgciWAfA==/base.apk)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.<clinit>(ListenRequest.java:849)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest.getDefaultInstance(ListenRequest.java:854)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.FirestoreGrpc.getListenMethod(FirestoreGrpc.java:396)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.<init>(WatchStream.java:61)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.createWatchStream(Datastore.java:115)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.<init>(RemoteStore.java:167)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider.createRemoteStore(MemoryComponentProvider.java:72)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ComponentProvider.initialize(ComponentProvider.java:135)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(FirestoreClient.java:258)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0(FirestoreClient.java:105)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:436)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$2.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:322)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Test running failed: Process crashed.
Tests ran to completion.
```

[tried this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1907), doesn't work.
[this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154727/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-registerdefaultinstance-with-fireb) didn't work.

Comment: Why you don't provide the `build.gradle`? And it's also duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance with Firebase Performance and Espresso Instrumented Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154727/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-registerdefaultinstance-with-fireb).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `protobuf-javalite` is what you may want to build against.

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1907) and with high probability, it is being caused by parts of the `build.gradle`, which you've withheld. All I can tell is that excluding module `protobuf-javalite` strips out static method `registerDefaultInstance`;  therefore one should just exclude `protobuf-java` instead:

```
configurations.all() { configuration ->
    // exclude group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-javalite"
    exclude group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-java"
}
```

---

To use the Kotlin dependency might also make sense, but this should not be the cause:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:22.1.2'
```

To check what is actually being packaged: `./gradlew :app:dependencies > dependencies.txt`.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the dependencies.txt. I see I have io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite as a transitive dependency. But trying to exclude that also doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution @JimClermonts?